# Dumping raw html to a Telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

I have an MVC3 app that uses a Telerik grid. I have a variable with html in it i want to display raw:

```
   o.RawHtml = "This is a <br/> Test";

   @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
   .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.RawHtml).ClientTemplate("<#= RawHtml #>").Title("Raw");

       })
```

According to Telerik samples, this should work, but it doesnt. The output in a browser shows
        "This is a < br/> Test"

and not the desired:

```
  This is a
  Test
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It has something to do with .Encoded I've had that problem before with their controls. Have a look thru their forum searching for that

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `Encoded` property of the column to `false`? [This page](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-columns.html) gives some information.

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Orders")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Encoded(false);
    })
%>
```

By default, columns are html encoded.